# iOS Ad-hoc App: Cannot be installed at this time

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an app my company built for a client.  We had to register our Mac with the Apple developer site to do this, etc. etc.

Now 4 months later the previously-working .ipa file that is hosted online can no longer install to any iPad: not even an iPad that could previously install it!

iOS hasn't been updated, the package hasn't changed, but it does appear that the client mucked around with their signing certificates on Apple's devleoper site.

Would this cause this issue?  If I recreate a valid provisioning file and recompile the app, archive it for ad-hoc distribution, etc. etc. am I just going to have this problem again later (i.e. when my signing certificate expires and/or the client's Apple developer license expires)?

Comment: Ah ha, so it is.  I hadn't found that in my searches, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Developer ad-hoc provisioning profiles (technically, the certificate) expire after 90 days. Distribution ad-hoc provisioning profiles expire after 1 year.

Simply renew your profile and your certificate and rebuild or re-sign your archive.

Apps distributed with an Enterprise account do not expire, and neither do apps distributed through the App Store.

Comment: Does this include Enterprise ad-hoc distribution?
Edit: didn't read far enough down.  Heh.